# Setting the TestNG group name at class level

Tags: testing, testng

TestNG groups annotation is declared at test method level, that is, you can specify which group or groups a specific test method can belong to.

eg.

```
@Test(groups = { "group1", "group2" }, priority = 10, enabled = true)
    public void doTest() {}
```

For a given scenario where all test methods only belong to a single group, it almost seems like an overhead to specify the group name in each test method. Is there a way, in this case, to set the group name at a higher (class) level?

Comment: I think you can put `@Test` annotation at class level - and therefore `groups` attribute too. Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it this way at class level.

```
@Test(groups = GROUP_EXAMPLE)
public class ClassExample {

@Test
public void methodExample() {

}
}
```

Hopefully it helped!